# this.setState doesn't work in my arrow function

Tags: reactjs

I just want to output the content inside the Input inside the paragraph below, but I don't know why it doesn't work.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Person from "./Person/Person";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    persons: [
      { id: 'vcxlkmk', name: "Eriko", age: 33 },
      { id: 'blablab', name: "Manu", age: 20 },
      { id: 'v393993', name: "Boulaï", age: 5 }
    ],
    otherState: "dsqdsq",
    showPersons: false,
    textLength: ''
  }
  nameChangeHandler = (event, id) => {
    // for each persons return the person which get the id equal to id parameter
    const personIndex = this.state.persons.findIndex(e => { 
      return e.id === id
    });

    // DONT alter the original state object. Always making copy
    const person = {
      ...this.state.persons[personIndex]
    }

    person.name = event.target.value
    person[personIndex] = person;

    this.setState({
      persons: [
        { name: "Eric", age: 33 },
        { name: event.target.value, age: 54 },
        { name: "Boulaï", age: 44 }
      ],
      otherState: this.state.otherState
    });
  }

  deletePersonHandler = personIndex => {
    // we perform a shallow copy with the spread ES6 operator
    // that copy over the value NOT the pointer.
    const persons = [...this.state.persons];

    // deep copy with recursion
    const clone = (items) => items.map(item => Array.isArray(item) ? clone(item) : item);
    const personDeep = clone(this.state.persons);
    console.log(personDeep);
    // The splice() method adds/removes items to/from an array, 
    personDeep.splice(personIndex, 1);

    this.setState({
      persons: personDeep
    })
  }

  togglePersonsHandler = () => {
    const showOff = this.state.showPersons;
    this.setState({
      showPersons: !showOff
    });
  }

  textLengthHandler = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState = ({
      textLength: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    let persons = null;

    if (this.state.showPersons) {
      persons = (
        <div>
          {this.state.persons.map((e, index) => {
            return (
              <Person
                clickclick={() => this.deletePersonHandler(index)}
                name={e.name}
                age={e.age}
                key={e.id}
                changed={() => this.nameChangeHandler(e.event, e.id)}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Je suis eric</h1>
        <button onClick={() => this.togglePersonsHandler()}>Togglze</button>
        {persons}
          <input type="text" onChange={this.textLengthHandler}/>
          <p>Text length: {this.state.text} </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

// copyHandler = () => alert('text copied!');
```

I don't know why in my textLengthHandler I got the value into my function, but I'm not able to update my state.

```
textLengthHandler = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState = ({
      textLength: event.target.value
    });
  }
```

Comment: Very hard to follow all that code, try to minimize it to only what is relevant for your question

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning a value to `this.setState` when you should call it as a function, you should do:

```
textLengthHandler = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({
      textLength: event.target.value
    });
}
```

Comment: waaaaa , thanks you bro !!! I didn't even noticed it, I'm on it since somethings like 4 hours !

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining the the setState method by saying 'this.setState = ...' so state wont change. You need to pass the object to the setState method like so:

```
this.setState({
  textLength: event.target.value
});
```